# Visual Studio - Debugging Typescript in Local NPM Package Used by .NET5 Hosted React App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio, debugging, npm

I'm developing an NPM package, using Typescript, that is meant to be consumed in React apps. Straightforward right? I also have a sample/test application that is a .NET Core-hosted React app (straight from the VS2019 template, plus Typescript added through NPM). Though building everything and debugging the sample app works fine, I have not been able to get Visual Studio to debug the Typescript files in the local NPM package.

The NPM package is an NJSProj. I build it by using `"build": "tsc"` in `scripts` in `package.json`. My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,    
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "target": "es2019",
    "lib": [ "es2019", "dom" ],
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,    
    "module": "ESNext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "listFiles": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

For the sample/test consuming app, I have a .NET5-hosted React application built straight from the VS2019 template, plus Typescript installed through npm. To get the sample app to consume the local package, I use `npm link` in the package folder. Then, in the sample app's `ClientApp` folder, after `npm install` I use `npm link mypackagename` to create the dependency.

In my sample app's code, I'm able to import the local package using `import * as MyPackage from 'mypackagename';`, consume its exports, and it all builds and runs fine. But I cannot get Typescript debugging to work in Visual Studio.

Any breakpoints I set in the .TS files in my package are never "bound" at runtime. Moreover, if I set a breakpoint in the sample app JS/TS code, before any call into my package, and step into my package's code, it steps into the compiled Javascript version (not the main bundle version, interestingly), and not the original TS code. The individual source maps are all there, and in addition the current line is wrong for the Javascript version but would be correct for the Typescript version, which makes me think it is indeed applying the .MAP file but just not finding the .TS. Another odd thing is that Intellisense in the sample app code sees my package and its exports fine, and I'm able to F12 into a class or function name referenced by my sample consuming app and it opens the correct TS file out of my local package source. So Visual Studio clearly knows how to find the source code and appears even to be seeing the MAP files, but won't let me set breakpoints and doesn't navigate to the correct files after Step In.

One avenue I tried was to use `eject` on the sample React app to see if I could modify `webpack.config.js` directly and try to force it to compile the Typescript in my package rather than use TSC in a separate build step, but I couldn't seem to find the right entries that needed to be changed (the create-react-app -generated webpack.config.js is a monster).

I also tried changing my `tsconfig` settings as such:

```
 "sourceMap": false,
 "inlineSources": true,
 "inlineSourceMap": true,
```

This was a step in the right direction, as I could now at least step into my package's TS files if I set a breakpoint in the sample app. However, Visual Studio still would not associate this with the actual TS files on my disk, and I still could not set breakpoints in those files in the NSProj.

Finally note to be clear this is Visual Studio 2019, NOT Visual Studio Code. I've not tried Code yet, but I want to stick with full VS2019 if possible.

So two main questions arise:

1. How can I actually debug my package's Typescript files at runtime within Visual Studio?
2. Possibly related, is there a different build process I should be using for the local npm package? I note that with this method, hot reload is impossible because I have to rebuild it each time using `tsc`. I would much prefer that my sample app compile my package's TS source code along with the code for the sample app itself, but this is where I suspect I would have to delve deep within the guts of the React build scripts and I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to these build chains.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, after a good 10 hours of trial and error between yesterday and today I stumbled upon the magical combination that worked.

- I don't need to build the npm package using `tsc` in order to debug. In fact the local package's `tsconfig.json` will wind up being ignored during debug runs. Instead I figured out how to get webpack to include the local module source files during the build of the sample consuming app
- I did have to use `npm run eject` on the sample consuming app, to expand out all the hidden scripts, most importantly `webpack.config.json`
- I continue to use `npm link` as described above
- In `scripts/paths.js` (which is created after `eject`) I had to add a `localModuleSrc` path to my module source, alongside `appSrc` which is just the `src` folder
- The lynchpin was I had to modify `webpack.config.json` to use `awesome-typescript-loader` instead of babel. `babel-loader` patently refused to compile Typescript files outside of `src`. I then used this for everything in `appSrc` and `localModuleSrc`:

```
{
      test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
      include: [paths.appSrc, paths.localModuleSrc],
      loader: require.resolve('awesome-typescript-loader'),
},
```

- Finally I had to add `dev-tool: 'source-map'` just before `plugins`. Without this, debugging sortof worked but breakpoints were always off by 1 or 2 lines.

And then, to my astonishment, breakpoints in both my local package source and my sample consuming app started hitting.

So the bottom line seems to be that `babel-loader` is unsuitable for this use case because I guess it won't touch anything outside of `src`. But `awesome-typescript-loader` lives up to its name.